# What is the meaning of 'collapsing the piece with the punch/drift' (and the rest of the sentences)?

Tags: sentence-meaning, terminology

I want to know the translation of this sentence

I have seen this article on the web.
But I can translate this sentence into our language. (Korean)
What is the exact meaning of the sentence below.
The part I can not understand is this.

> "One major issue I knew I would encounter was collapsing the piece with the punch/drift. I inserted a piece of hollow round stock I had lying around."

I attach the picture so that you can understand better the meaning of the sentence in the context. Please tell me the meaning of the sentence above.

[image]

Comment: It would have been better to change or edit your old post to include this information and question, since it is about the same article.

Answer (score 2):

This should be clearer:

> One major issue I knew that I would encounter was accidentally collapsing the piece when working with the punch/drift. To prevent this, I inserted a piece of hollow round stock I had nearby.

Stock is a piece of metal. Punch and drift seem to be tools he is using.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto to modulusshift, but with "closer captions<sup>1</sup>":

> *One major issue I knew I would encounter*
>   = One big problem I knew I might have
>
> *was collapsing the piece with the punch/drift.*
>   = was that I could damage my workpiece with my tool called punch/drift.
>
> *I inserted a piece of hollow round stock*
>   = To prevent that, I inserted that cylinder-looking piece of metal, which is hollow like a tube
>
> *I had lying around.*
>   = which happened to lie around somewhere in my shop.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Pun intended. "closer captions" is non-standard; it's "closer" as in "have a closer look at the text".</sub>